# Android:Scroll/Fling 3 listviews simultaneously

Tags: android

How to scroll three listviews with different row layouts simultaneously?
Overriding onScroll() doesnt give exact behaviour as onScroll gets called multiple times for single scroll and is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer finally :
override onTouchEvent() for the listview class and do not call super.onTouchEvent(). Instead calcualte difference between y positions of MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and scroll the three lists together by calling smoothScrollBy(distance,time) for each of the list. You may do fine tuning for three lists as required on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.